# Get current date from datetime.datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I'm trying to get current date so I can pass it to the DATE field in SQL. I'm using datetime.datetime, below is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime(datetime.today().date(), "%m/%d/%Y").date()
```

However, i'm getting this error:

`TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime`

How can I fix the issue above? I'm still confused about datetime and datetime.datetime, and i want to keep using `from datetime import datetime` not `import datetime`.

How can I fix the issue above? thank you

Comment: Use `datetime.strftime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see closely, the result of following statement,

```
>>> datetime.today().date()
datetime.date(2019, 9, 30)
>>> str(datetime.today().date())
'2019-09-30'
```

You'll notice that the datetime returned is `-` seperated and you'll have to convert it explicitly to a string value. Hence, for the above statement to work, change it to :

```
dt = datetime.strptime(str(datetime.today().date()), "%Y-%M-%d").date()
```

Then change it to whatever format you desire for using `strftime` (in your case >>> `"%d/%m/%Y"`)

```
>>> dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
'30/01/2019'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
print(dt)
```

Prints:

```
'09/30/2019'
```

`strptime` takes a string and makes a `datetime` object. Whereas `strftime` does exactly the opposite, taking a `datetime` object and returning a string.